# Is there a way to view web usage reports for a specific page?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, analytics

I know how to get to the Site Usage Analytics, but my teammate is asking if we can discern how many hits specific pages are getting.

For Example, we have a sub-site which features many reviews by topic. Each topic has it's own page. We want to see which pages get the most hits aka which topic is getting the most interest.

We used the ranking options, but it showed analytics for the whole site, which is huge, so our pages didn't even show up on it.

We are using SharePoint 2010.

Any insight?

Answer (score 1):

Analytics are divide into 3 categories **Traffic, Search, Inventory**, your answer is in the Traffic category.

If you go the `Site collection web analytics reports` or `Site Web Analytics reports` on that page you will see Summary and left hand side under the Traffic, you will see the top pages. I think this is what you looking for.

- **Top Pages:** Most viewed pages in the current entit
- **Top Visitors:** Most frequent visitors of the current entity.
- **Top Referrers:** Top URL’s external to the current entity from where
  users navigated to the current entity.
- **Top Destinations:** Similar to Referrers, these are the top external
  URL’s that the user visited from the current entity.
- **Top Browsers:** Top browsers being used to visit the current entity

[Web Analytics in SharePoint 2010: Insights into Reports and Metrics](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ecm/archive/2010/05/03/web-analytics-in-sharepoint-2010-insights-into-reports-and-metrics.aspx)

something like this:

[image]

Comment: Yes, I know that, but instead of viewing by top pages, I want to view the hits of specific pages. Not have them automatically ranked.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt this is still an issue for you, but what you are looking for is the "Top Destinations" section. It allows you to enter a url to pull analytics for. Just click on the Top Destinations link in the left nav, than select Filter in the Analytics ribbon at the top of the page.